# I need to compare values between two sheets to find matching items

Tags: google-sheets

I need to compare two different sheets to find matching values between them.

In the first sheet, I have a list of order numbers and in the second one, I have a list that needs dispatching. Therefore, without scrolling through the sheet manually for the 1000+, I'd like to use a formula or conditional formatting in order to flag the values that are the same (or all of the different values) so I can simply copy and paste this into another sheet.

I have shared a link to a google sheet below if someone could help with this that would be very much appreciated.

Edit: The second sheet (on the google document) is the list of all orders and the first are the ones to be dispatched. I need to know which one's from the second sheet are missing from the first.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18vSBu9GzxK1UMCE2RrDyNSH6yi-FzTvuABsVw9r172Y/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

In second sheet in column B you could do:

`=COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,A2)`

IF the formula returns 0, it means that id number **is not** in your first sheet.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!